# my current website is "http://extranet" i would like to change this to "http://extranet.domainname.com" on a Windows Server 2003 R2 with IIS 6.0

Tags: iis

Situation: current website is "http://extranet" i would like to change this to "http://extranet.domainname.com" this site is configured on the same server where the IIS, DHCP and DNS is. i would like to change the sitename to "http://extranet.domainname.COM" but know that the domain is a "domainname.LOCAL" so how do i make shure i can type

thank you in advance!

Manu

Comment: I took a shot at the answer, but you **really** need to provide more information about the network, DNS, firewall, domain, and intended use.

Answer (score 1):

Is your DNS server an authoritative name server for the domain? Then simply add an A or CNAME record to your DNS entries and point it to the IP address or an alternate fully qualified hostname of your server. Once you do that go into IIS, find the website and add the hostname to the website filter.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here we go.  I am making assumptions (which I shall state).  Please clarify in these areas by EDITING YOUR QUESTION rather than commenting.

Assumptions:
A1- The website works internally.
A2- You want the website to work across the internet.
A3- The domain "domainname.com" already exists on the internet.

First, you need to identify an external IP address for the extranet, and you need to setup NAT on your firewall to router traffic from that external IP address to the actual server. How this is done depends on the firewall, but is a standard firewall function. Look in the firewall documentation, on their site, or search here for NAT and the firewall.

Then, you want to add a CNAME record to the internal DNS to map "extranet.domainname.com" to "extranet" (or "extranet.domainname.local"). This should make the FQDN work internally.

Finally, you need to add an "A record" to the "domainname.com" internet DNS zone mapping "extranet.domainname.com" to the external IP address created above. Whoever administers the "domainname.com" domain can do this. This should (after a delay of a few hours) make the external access work properly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

well thanks for the support, i found it... the domain name is a ".local" so i had so make a new zone.. the now zone had the same name juist ".com" so i had two zones, "mysite.local" and a "mysite.com" afther i did that i had to make a new A record in the new zone, with name mysite.com and the ipadress of the server wich mysite is on. then i go back to the IIS and change the header of the site to "mysite.com" port 80 and the right IP. that worked for me fine!

thanks for the help and efforts!

Manu